# Change the output of an array

Tags: python

I am currently working with the Node_Coords_Section of the berlin52.tsp file

This gives the following output:

```
{1: [565.0, 575.0], 2: [25.0, 185.0], 3: [345.0, 750.0], 4: [945.0, 685.0], 5: [845.0, 655.0], ....}
```

In order to be able to use satsp, I need to change the latter in this format:

```
[[1, 566.0, 575.0], [2, 25.0, 185.0], [3, 345.0, 750.0], .....]
```

What should I do to get it in this format?

Comment: `list(cities.values())`

Comment: That works, however I also need to include the ID of the city, in this case being 1,2,3,etc

Comment: Are the dictionary keys always integers? And do you need the original order to be kept?

Comment: Yes the dictionary keys are always integers, and the original order needs to be kept preferrably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use
`lst = [[x,*y] for x, y in dic.items()]`

Here is the full code:

```
dic = {1: [565.0, 575.0], 2: [25.0, 185.0], 3: [345.0, 750.0], 4: [945.0, 685.0], 5: [845.0, 655.0]}

lst = [[x,*y] for x, y in dic.items()]

print(lst)
```

OP: `[[1, 565.0, 575.0], [2, 25.0, 185.0], [3, 345.0, 750.0], [4, 945.0, 685.0], [5, 845.0, 655.0]]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked as intended

Comment: @pepegaClap hit the tick beside the answer if that worked for you.

Comment: I tried however the system doesn't let me :(

Comment: An error pops up like this: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) like this:

```
>>> cities = {1: [565.0, 575.0], 2: [25.0, 185.0], 3: [345.0, 750.0], 4: [945.0, 685.0], 5: [845.0, 655.0]}
>>> [[k] + v for k, v in cities.items()]
[[1, 565.0, 575.0], [2, 25.0, 185.0], [3, 345.0, 750.0], [4, 945.0, 685.0], [5, 845.0, 655.0]]
```